# How do I get a fluid table to work with ellipsis?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, ellipsis

Let's say I have a table with two columns, I would like the right column width to be size of the contents within the table-cell and the left column width to be as wide as possible. I would also like the left column not to line wrap and display ellipsis.

I have created a jsfiddle example here http://jsfiddle.net/fTd8m/

```
<style type="text/css">
.parent{
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.left-column{
    display:table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.right-column{
    text-align:right;
    display:table-cell;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="left-column">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        Right Column
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is getting the left column to be as wide as possible.
If I remove the css table-layout:fixed; the ellipsis doesn't work as expected.

How do I get a fluid table to work with ellipsis ?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add an paragraph element styled with inner-block. Then I used jQuery to iterate trough all the elements in the right column measuring the max width of them. Then I assigned the max width to the column.

You can find my solution under this jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jvgRV/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    //go through each paragraph in the right column and find the widest value.
    $(".innerParagraph").each(function() {
        if(maxWidth < $(this).width()){
            maxWidth = $(this).width();
        }
    });
    // assign max width to column
    $(".right-column").width(maxWidth);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.table{
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
.left-column{
    display:table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.right-column{
    text-align:right;
    display:table-cell;
}
.innerParagraph{
    display:inline-block;   
}
</style>

<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-column">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="right-column">
            <p class="innerParagraph">Right Column</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="left-column">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
        <div class="right-column">
            <p class="innerParagraph">Right Column wider</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```